# Error while installing web3 on vscode Windows 10

Tags: python

I have been trying to install web3 using 'pip install web3'. I am getting the following error.

After looking at a few other threads I have already installed Visual Studio Build Tools from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16

However, the error persists. I do not have the log from the error I installed the build tools. From what I remember it was also related to cytoolz, but the error was slightly different. The current error is below. I have already spent 4 hours trying to fix this, any help is much appreciated.

```
  Running setup.py install for cytoolz ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\A\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dnghcqjq\\cytoolz_26dc3d7054a14b8fa2d483e2f670ba5d\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\A\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dnghcqjq\\cytoolz_26dc3d7054a14b8fa2d483e2f670ba5d\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-it_4rnu0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\cytoolz'
         cwd: C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dnghcqjq\cytoolz_26dc3d7054a14b8fa2d483e2f670ba5d\
    Complete output (70 lines):
    ALERT: Cython not installed.  Building without Cython.
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz     
    copying cytoolz\utils_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz        
    copying cytoolz\_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz       
    copying cytoolz\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\operator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz        
    copying cytoolz\functoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz        
    copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz        
    copying cytoolz\recipes.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\utils.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\cpython.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz        
    copying cytoolz\functoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz        
    copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz        
    copying cytoolz\recipes.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\utils.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried_toolzlike.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_dicttoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_docstrings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_doctests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_embedded_sigs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_functoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_inspect_args.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_itertoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_none_safe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_recipes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_serialization.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_tlz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    running build_ext
    building 'cytoolz.dicttoolz' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\cytoolz
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tccytoolz/dicttoolz.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\cytoolz/dicttoolz.obj
    dicttoolz.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64 /EXPORT:PyInit_dicttoolz build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\cytoolz/dicttoolz.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\dicttoolz.cp310-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\cytoolz\dicttoolz.cp310-win_amd64.lib
       Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\cytoolz\dicttoolz.cp310-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\cytoolz\dicttoolz.cp310-win_amd64.exp
    Generating code
    Finished generating code
    building 'cytoolz.functoolz' extension
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tccytoolz/functoolz.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\cytoolz/functoolz.obj
    functoolz.c
    cytoolz/functoolz.c(23087): warning C4013: '_PyGen_Send' undefined; assuming extern returning int
    cytoolz/functoolz.c(23087): warning C4047: '=': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
    cytoolz/functoolz.c(23092): warning C4047: '=': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
    cytoolz/functoolz.c(23176): warning C4047: '=': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64 /EXPORT:PyInit_functoolz build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\cytoolz/functoolz.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\functoolz.cp310-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\cytoolz\functoolz.cp310-win_amd64.lib
       Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\cytoolz\functoolz.cp310-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\cytoolz\functoolz.cp310-win_amd64.exp
    functoolz.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PyGen_Send    
    build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\functoolz.cp310-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed 
with exit code 1120
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\A\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dnghcqjq\\cytoolz_26dc3d7054a14b8fa2d483e2f670ba5d\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\A\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dnghcqjq\\cytoolz_26dc3d7054a14b8fa2d483e2f670ba5d\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-it_4rnu0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\cytoolz' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out. I need to install cython using 'pip install cython'. this fixed the issue